# Unity3d C# Translate не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    bool t = false;
    public int plspeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("start");
        StartCoroutine(wait1());
    }

    void stt()
    {
        StopCoroutine(wait1());
        Debug.Log("stop stt");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator wait1()
    {
        Debug.Log("start IEnumerator");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        obj.transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * plspeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("stop waitforseconds");
        stt();
        Debug.Log("stop IEnumerator");
    }
}
```

Translate просто телепортирует объект через две секунды. Моя задача сделать движение объекта так: в одну сторону две секунды, в другую сторону две секунды и так бесконечно.

Answer (score 2):

Вызывать корутину в корутине - плохо, вызывать корутины в больших количествах в целом плохо, потому что это не самое дешевое занятие. Если нужно сделать таймер - нужно это делать через `while(true)` или схожий цикл, запускать по корутине за итерацию - такая себе затея.

---

Что вы написали, то и происходит:

1. `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);` - подождать 2 секунды
2. `obj.transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * plspeed * Time.deltaTime);` - сдвинуть объект за 1 кадр
3. повторить

Учитывая, что объекту нужно каждые 2 секунды менять направление на противоположное, проще поручить корутине менять направление каждые 2 секунды, а в самом `Update()` двигать объект:

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject obj;

    public Vector3 moveVector = -Vector3.right;
    public float speed;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(ControlDirection());
    }

    void Update() {
        obj.transform.Translate(moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    IEnumerator ControlDirection() {
        // необходимо рано или поздно выйти из этого цикла
        // при смене уровня, например
        // для этого нужно добавить какой-то механизм выхода из корутины
        // и ее повторного запуска, но это уже отдельный вопрос
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            speed *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Получаем закономерный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]